# Windows 11 installation from USB fails with 'incompatible' error, while Windows Setup says it's compatible

Tags: windows-11

I'm currently running Windows 10 Pro, and from time to time receive reminders asking me to upgrade to Windows 11. 
Also when I run the PC Health Check application it says my pc meets all the requirements completely. 
(TPM 2.0, Ryzen 7 3700x proc, 32 GB memory, 1 TB SSD, AMD Radeon RX 6800).

However, when I try to install Windows 11 next to my current Windows 10 installation from a USB thumb drive (created with the Media Creation tool from Microsoft), the wizard won't let me install Windows 11, saying my pc is incompatible (no specific component or error). 
I choose not to enter a serial number, and select Windows 11 Pro or Pro N. 
After that it shows this message and stops.

Does anyone know what the problem might be, and how to fix it?

Cheers,
CJ

Comment: Try running WhyNotWin11  (GitHub) and see what it says.  If the CPU new enough?

Comment: Everything is green...

Comment: try to install Windows 11 next to my current Windows 10 installation   ....  It has to replace the Windows 10 install (licensing).

Comment: The Microsoft documentation says it should be possible to do a clean install.
I have a digital license linked to my MS account, so activation should be possible later during the installation.

Comment: It still needs to install and then disable the Windows 10 license since you are upgrading.

Comment: I kinda doubt that (as of today) it would actually prevent you to use the same key/account to activate Windows 10 again after you activated Windows 11 once, although I have never actually tested. Also it would seem silly if Windows Setup can't even give you a concrete error or force you to overwrite the Windows 10 installation. But meh Microsoft. Btw is your current installation a UEFI/GPT one? (A screenshot of Disk Management should tell.)

Comment: It’s not a licensing issue. You don’t even have to enter a key to install windows. It sounds like you want to try to dual boot the system and that is likely where your problem is. There are two typical paths - upgrade the existing OS by starting setup within Windows. Or, do a clean install by booting from a USB installer and using the custom install option and deleting all existing partitions off the drive. The problem here is you have not provided screenshots or exact steps and options you are taking during setup and dual booting has specific requirements.

Comment: Dual booting requires a properly partitioned disk drive with free space. If you aren’t upgrading or replacing the existing OS then you likely have not properly prepared the disk for dual booting.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear if you are trying to install Windows 11 over top of Windows 10, or if you are trying to install Windows 11 as a dual boot system with Windows 10.

Dual boot has specific requirements which you likely have not met.

There are two “upgrade” paths available. Option 1, you can start Windows Setup from within a running Windows system, and directly upgrade the OS to Windows 11.

Or, you can boot from the installation media and choose a “Custom” install.

The only option that works here will be “Custom.”
[image]

Following that, you need to delete the existing partitions from the disk drive so Windows can recreate everything it needs. This is called a “clean” install and will wipe the old OS and data from the drive.

A drive ready for a clean install will not have any existing partitions on it:
[image]

If you want to install Windows 11 as a dual-boot system, then you would need to first repartition your existing disk drive(s) so that there is free, unpartitioned space available for the OS to install on. This happens before you start Windows setup and often involves third party partition management tools that can shrink and resize partitions. There are many articles available about how to do this.

The most widely used and accepted path to upgrade is option 1 above. Start setup from within Windows 10 and upgrade directly to Windows 11. This will keep your applications and data. After, you’ll have 10 days to downgrade back to Windows 10 if you have issues. Otherwise, backup your data and perform a clean install by deleting all the existing partitions on disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Consumer Windows License (OEM (most likely) or Retail) and not a Corporate license, then the Windows 11 install must replace the Windows 10 Install.

You cannot keep both Windows 11 and Windows 10 from the same upgrade process on the same computer.

If you have a Retail license (less likely), you can install Windows 10 on a different computer and upgrade the different computer to Windows 11.  The old computer still has Windows 10 but it cannot be run at the same time as the Windows 11 computer. Remember, there are two computers here in this paragraph.

If you do as above (install on the same computer and WhyNotWin11 is all green) then it should install.

If it continues to fail, contact Microsoft Support.

Comment: This isn’t an answer to the question. Licensing is a legal matter not a technical matter and I’m pretty sure [su] frowns on offering legal and licensing advice. I researched and am uncertain if your statements about licensing are correct. Use rights vary based on the underlying license (OEM, Retail, VLK, etc) and the primary limitation is that only a single copy of the licensed OS may run at a time. Using the same license to run Windows 10 or Windows 11 on the same device and at different times may not be a violation of the license. Any activation issues can be resolved by calling Microsoft.

Comment: I have not seen any Microsoft article that says you can start with Windows 10, upgrade to Windows 11 on the same machine and keep both. So I think my answer covers this. OEM for sure you cannot keep both. If Retail, you can move the Windows 10 license to a new machine, upgrade there and keep the Windows 10 machine. But they must not be used at the same time.

Comment: Microsoft licensing terms are confusing if anything. Depending on where you look you can find all kinds of inaccurate information. Our perspective and understanding of licensing isn’t really important here. The OP is not asking about licensing and licensing is not the problem here. It’s not an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, confusing, but at least this:  To upgrade to Windows 11 from Windows 10, this has to be done on the same computer, that is, start with Windows 10, run the upgrade and end with Windows 11. On the same computer, the Windows 10 license has been used to be the Windows 11 license. This is what I said.